# List all projects in organization inside Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I want to list all projects inside organization. I have all permissions in Service Account (=> Browser, Compute Viewer, Folder Viewer, Organisation Viewer) but when I make an API call from my cloud function I got error:

{'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'The caller does not have permission', 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}

My Python function is pretty simple:

```
credentials, project = google.auth.default()
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request() 
credentials.refresh(request) 
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)


 def get_all_projects(self) -> list:
    '''
    Return list of all GCP projects inside oraganization
    '''
    

    request_url = 'https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v3/projects'
    print("Making a request to ", request_url)
    response = authed_session.request(
                        'GET', request_url)
    data = response.json()
  
    return data
```

Do you have any idea why I have PERMISSION_DENIED?

Comment: How did you configure the service account that Cloud Functions is using? The function is not using your user identity.

Comment: @JohnHanley is right. You have to grant the correct roles on the organisation to allow the Service Account of the Cloud Functions to read the projects/folders of your org

Comment: Did the above comments help you to resolve the issue?